# Series thyristor circuit

Tags: power-electronics, thyristor, synchronization, dc-blocking

I want to build a pulsed energy source and consider up to 6 kV for the storage capacitor voltage. The application is similar to a defibrillator but not for medical purposes. So any insights into what thyristors are in defibrillators is welcome, too. The load will be a few Ω, expected peak currents would be around 500 A.

At such blocking voltages, the only kind of thyristors I was able to find were the fat (and costly) disc types. As the energies will be only moderate (several 100 J, only a fraction of which will be dissipated in the thyristors), these seem to be overkill to me. I was thinking of using smaller thyristors in series to achieve the necessary blocking voltage ([random example part](https://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/MCC21-16io8B.pdf), maybe even two of these for 4 SCRs total), similar to several diodes in series for extended blocking capabilities.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffK1pU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When considering the thyristors as mere logical switches, then any slight out-of-sync triggering will lead to the full voltage appearing on the slower one of them. But I have seen [applications/devices](https://www.behlke.com/pdf/120-100-scr.pdf) that claim to use series thyristors.

Even when they are triggered via optocouplers (i.e. the slowest case) that have their primary LEDs in series, the trigger signal should be fairly well synced - I expect well below 1 µs of skew. The thyristors themselves (according to the datasheet) take a few µs max. to fire after the gate pulse.

The load can go either on the high-side of the thyristors or on the low-side, if that makes a difference for the driving. In any case the control circuitry for the drive will be isolated from the HV circuit.

### Question

Is it fine to place them in series and use synchronized trigger pulses (like described above) to fire them? Is there some special ingredient needed to make it work, other than *"make sure the gate pulses are synced to <1 µs"*?

Comment: You'll need balancing circuits I believe. Where does the load go?

Comment: From someone who has to run devices in series at work every day - avoid series connection of semiconductors at all costs. Yes, it can be done but paying 10 times more for a single device which can take the entire voltage directly is your better option unless massive mass production quantities.

Comment: @winny Thanks for the input, are you talking about unipolar FETs? I imagine those would be a whole lot harder to discipline than sluggish bipolar ones. But as I start excavating my rabbit hole, I sure hear you. I'm about 1 day of research away from yelling: "Shut up and take my money" 

Comment: @tobalt All semiconductors. Sure you can get it to work on your desk, but move that to mass production with production spread and fault cases to be handled and you are in a world of issues. If one-off, just pay for the voltage rating straight up and be done with it.

Comment: @winny I think I would rather invest the day of research into finding better parts that satisfy the spec then :) If you want, I would still be interested in an answer of yours, that provides a little insight into your work in synchronizing these devices. Just to keep the SE question neat and answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need equalisation for both static and dynamic behaviour.

As all of us are aware, the I-V and reverse recovery characteristics of the same brand/model SCRs are similar but not equal due to practical limitations. This means that series-connected SCRs will not share the total voltage equally (same leakage will drop different blocking voltage), and also the turn-on and -off behaviours will be different.

---

For **static equalisation**, resistors will work just like we do for series-connected capacitors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fybHFn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Selection of the resistor requires the max allowed blocking voltage and leakage current across/through each SCR to be taken into account i.e. the current flowing through the resistors should be higher enough than the leakage currents so that the leakages can be neglected.

---

For **dynamic equalisation**, normally a simple RC would work. But as we already have an R across the SCR, a parallel C would do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxiRvB.png)</sup>

For further improvement, a series resistor can be added in series with the capacitor to limit di/dt during discharge when the respective SCR turns on (just to protect the SCR from ridiculous current, nothing else):-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQyftt.png)</sup>

This RC network is added to equalise (almost) the reverse recovery of the SCRs so that one doesn't turn-on or -off before the other.

This extra resistance (Rc1 or Rc2) will affect the charging time of the parallel caps. So, to decrease charging time we can add a fast diode in parallel with these resistances (charge up through diode - faster, discharge through resistor - slower but safer for the SCR):-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9NKa6.png)</sup>

I cannot make a calculation or give a formula to find the values, sorry. But I believe simulations would help a lot more than I could.

---

**EDIT:** This circuit given above is mainly for non-synced turn-off (reverse-recovery-related) problems but also helps to mitigate non-synced turn-on related problems as well. Consider the circuit below:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8la29.png)</sup>

Assuming the SCRs are settled at forward blocking (anode voltage is greater than or equal to cathode voltage, and no gate pulses applied). So the blocking voltages across the SCRs will be half the input voltage (with the help of static equaliser resistors).

In case of a non-synced firing, say SCR1 is triggered first, the voltage across the "late-triggered" SCR (SCR2) starts to rise having a time constant set by, with an oversimplification (i.e. The effect of SCR2's leakage, parallel diode across Rc2, etc are all neglected), the load resistance (R<sub>L</sub>) and the parallel-connected capacitance (C2 in this case).

The firing delay should be short enough than the aforementioned time constant in order for the voltage across SCR2 to rise as low as possible. If you don't have any control over the firing delay you can increase the time constant by increasing the capacitances. This will slow down the rise of the voltage across SCR2.

Comment: Thanks Rohat. About the second circuit for the dynamic load sharing, I fail to see how it can achieve that. When I fire one of the thyristors, wouldn't the capacitance next to it be instantly discharged, so again the full rail voltage would appear on the other thyristor?

Comment: @tobalt Weren't you thinking about synced firing? Why would you fire them individually?

Comment: Yes, they will be fired in sync (With a small potential skew from parasitic effects). But with the huge current capabilities of the thyristor (say it can easily discharge this capacitor at 1000 A), then even something large like 1 µF, would last only 1 ns. Crude numbers, true, but that is order of magnitude away from where it would be enough to keep the mid-point voltage stable for a few µs, isn't it?

Comment: An antiparallel diode may also be needed, to accommodate resonant current (reversal).

Comment: @tobalt see my edit.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for the additional explanations. I was neglecting the RL in my previous comment's estimations.

Answer (score 6):

I randomly have a [Velonex 510 Ring Generator](https://nscainc.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/V_510.pdf), which uses an SCR stack.  Here's an internal view:

[image: Internal View]

As you can see, they have a stack of six (optionally seven in another model, it would seem) SCRs in series.  The maximum supply voltage is 2.5kV (or maybe a modest factor greater than that, depending on how the output coupling network is designed), suggesting at least 600V SCRs were used. The red-potted black boxes appear to be gate-drive transformers, with triple isolated outputs; the 15R resistors are probably series gate resistance.  The 1M resistors are probably static equalizing divider resistors.

Curiously, they're even using pairs in parallel.  Evidently this works out well enough, and notice there are gate resistors per device to balance turn-on currents.

Underneath, and nearby, there are various capacitors, inductors and transformers for coupling the transient to the output terminals; these are not shown for simplicity of course (also, I don't particularly want to dig deeper inside this thing, lol).

Since the output is a ringing waveform, I expect drive is either a long square pulse to keep the SCRs on during the waveform, or rapid pulsing to the same end.  The bluish stud components are antiparallel diodes, to carry reaction current -- the output network is probably series resonant, i.e. when the SCR stack turns on, a large gulp of current is induced in the output network, which dutifully rings down, current reverses, the diodes conduct, current forwards, SCRs still conducting, etc. etc. until the decay is complete.

(Let me see here... The ring is evidently around 1.5MHz, which should be plenty fast enough that the SCRs don't recover; the burst being some 10s µs long, a square gate pulse is quite feasible with a ferrite-core transformer.)

If your waveform has multiple reversals, and a longer time constant, consider a tone-burst gate drive, and perhaps a DC-restore gate coupling network (i.e. rectify the gate pulses so it's never being reversed by transformer drive; a G-K resistor then affords turn-off, i.e. leakage and dV/dt immunity).

I would not recommend optical coupling, as the peak current and speed are likely inferior to other methods.  Or it's significantly more complexity, e.g. charging up a local capacitor to dump into the gate with some local logic; yeah, just toss a dumb transformer at it, easy as pie, and synchronized within, oh say, tens of ns.

Obviously, SCR ratings must be chosen in respect of the required dI/dt and peak current.  dI/dt is given in the datasheet, but peak current is harder to tell, as typically only fusing ratings are given (at 8.3 or 10ms), not the faster (~µs) pulses used in surge generators.  I've heard of "40kA peak" pucks being used successfully (n > 100s of shots?) in "quarter shrinker" application, so it's not impossible that this rating can be stretched quite a bit.  This may be a parameter you wish to characterize, or inquire further with the manufacturer about, depending on how much design assurance, peak capacity and cost you are looking for here.

Comment: Thanks for opening the generator ;) A magnetic gate drive circuit surely looks likely. I guess when synchronization is so important, one just shouldn't risk any shenanigans with slow optical coupling. Diodes are already in the design, in order to divert any significant reverse current/voltage.